# Adding Hyperlink via macro

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have a workbook (let's call it "GENERAL") which activates via macro a lot of other workbooks in a specific folder and pulls specific data over to GENERAL in order to build a total sum. I would like to automatically create a hyperlink on one of the copied values leading back to the specific workbook in order to be able to trace errors quickly. My code is the following:

```
MyPath = "Y:\test_workbook"
MyFile = Dir(MyPath)
Do While MyFile <> ""
If MyFile Like "*.xls" Or MyFile Like "*.xlsx" Then
Workbooks.Open MyPath & MyFile     

Sheets(1).Select
Range("A1") = myValue
Range("A1") = CDate(myValue)    
a = Range("A2").Value           ' here file-title 
b = Range("A3").Value          
c = Range("A4").Value           
f = Range("B1").Value

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True     
End If

Workbooks("GENERAL.xlsm").Activate    
Sheets("total").Cells(i, j) = a        
Sheets("total").Cells(i, j + b) = c

i = i + 1
MyFile = Dir

Loop
```

So: I want to create a Hyperlink in the workbook GENERAL which is mapped on the cell containing the A2-cell-information of the correlated workbook which provides the information and leads back to it.
Does anybody have a clue how this is done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't understand your context, but here's how you create hyperlink in Excel VBA:

```
With worksheet
   .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A2"), _ 
   Address:="http://www.stackoverflow.com", _ 
   ScreenTip:="Stack Overflow", _ 
   TextToDisplay:="StackOverflow" 
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped, with a bit of tuning I adapted it to my case.

Comment: @user36510 You're welcome, please accept it as your answer :)